# Binary bomb lab phase 6: Node values contain duplicates?

Tags: assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering, x86-64

```
     0x0000000000401161 <+0>:   push   %r14
     0x0000000000401163 <+2>:   push   %r13
     0x0000000000401165 <+4>:   push   %r12
     0x0000000000401167 <+6>:   push   %rbp
     0x0000000000401168 <+7>:   push   %rbx
     0x0000000000401169 <+8>:   sub    $0x50,%rsp
     0x000000000040116d <+12>:  lea    0x30(%rsp),%rsi
     0x0000000000401172 <+17>:  callq  0x40180a <read_six_numbers>
     0x0000000000401177 <+22>:  lea    0x30(%rsp),%r12
     0x000000000040117c <+27>:  mov    %r12,%r13
     0x000000000040117f <+30>:  mov    $0x0,%r14d
     0x0000000000401185 <+36>:  mov    %r13,%rbp
     0x0000000000401188 <+39>:  mov    0x0(%r13),%eax
     0x000000000040118c <+43>:  sub    $0x1,%eax
     0x000000000040118f <+46>:  cmp    $0x5,%eax
     0x0000000000401192 <+49>:  jbe    0x401199 <phase_6+56>
     0x0000000000401194 <+51>:  callq  0x4016a9 <explode_bomb>
     0x0000000000401199 <+56>:  add    $0x1,%r14d
     0x000000000040119d <+60>:  cmp    $0x6,%r14d
     0x00000000004011a1 <+64>:  je     0x4011c5 <phase_6+100>
     0x00000000004011a3 <+66>:  mov    %r14d,%ebx
     0x00000000004011a6 <+69>:  movslq %ebx,%rax

     0x00000000004011a9 <+72>:  mov    0x30(%rsp,%rax,4),%edx
     0x00000000004011ad <+76>:  cmp    %edx,0x0(%rbp)
     0x00000000004011b0 <+79>:  jne    0x4011b7 <phase_6+86>
     0x00000000004011b2 <+81>:  callq  0x4016a9 <explode_bomb>
     0x00000000004011b7 <+86>:  add    $0x1,%ebx
     0x00000000004011ba <+89>:  cmp    $0x5,%ebx
     0x00000000004011bd <+92>:  jle    0x4011a6 <phase_6+69>
     0x00000000004011bf <+94>:  add    $0x4,%r13
     0x00000000004011c3 <+98>:  jmp    0x401185 <phase_6+36>
     0x00000000004011c5 <+100>: lea    0x48(%rsp),%rcx
     0x00000000004011ca <+105>: mov    $0x7,%edx
     0x00000000004011cf <+110>: mov    %edx,%eax
     0x00000000004011d1 <+112>: sub    (%r12),%eax
     0x00000000004011d5 <+116>: mov    %eax,(%r12)
     0x00000000004011d9 <+120>: add    $0x4,%r12
     0x00000000004011dd <+124>: cmp    %rcx,%r12
     0x00000000004011e0 <+127>: jne    0x4011cf <phase_6+110>
     0x00000000004011e2 <+129>: mov    $0x0,%esi
     0x00000000004011e7 <+134>: jmp    0x401202 <phase_6+161>
     0x00000000004011e9 <+136>: mov    0x8(%rdx),%rdx
     0x00000000004011ed <+140>: add    $0x1,%eax
     0x00000000004011f0 <+143>: cmp    %ecx,%eax
     0x00000000004011f2 <+145>: jne    0x4011e9 <phase_6+136>

     0x00000000004011f4 <+147>: mov    %rdx,(%rsp,%rsi,2)
     0x00000000004011f8 <+151>: add    $0x4,%rsi
     0x00000000004011fc <+155>: cmp    $0x18,%rsi
     0x0000000000401200 <+159>: je     0x401217 <phase_6+182>
     0x0000000000401202 <+161>: mov    0x30(%rsp,%rsi,1),%ecx
     0x0000000000401206 <+165>: mov    $0x1,%eax
     0x000000000040120b <+170>: mov    $0x604300,%edx
     0x0000000000401210 <+175>: cmp    $0x1,%ecx
     0x0000000000401213 <+178>: jg     0x4011e9 <phase_6+136>
     0x0000000000401215 <+180>: jmp    0x4011f4 <phase_6+147>
     0x0000000000401217 <+182>: mov    (%rsp),%rbx
     0x000000000040121b <+186>: mov    0x8(%rsp),%rax
     0x0000000000401220 <+191>: mov    %rax,0x8(%rbx)
     0x0000000000401224 <+195>: mov    0x10(%rsp),%rdx
     0x0000000000401229 <+200>: mov    %rdx,0x8(%rax)
     0x000000000040122d <+204>: mov    0x18(%rsp),%rax
     0x0000000000401232 <+209>: mov    %rax,0x8(%rdx)
     0x0000000000401236 <+213>: mov    0x20(%rsp),%rdx
     0x000000000040123b <+218>: mov    %rdx,0x8(%rax)
     0x000000000040123f <+222>: mov    0x28(%rsp),%rax
     0x0000000000401244 <+227>: mov    %rax,0x8(%rdx)
     0x0000000000401248 <+231>: movq   $0x0,0x8(%rax)
     0x0000000000401250 <+239>: mov    $0x5,%ebp

     0x0000000000401255 <+244>: mov    0x8(%rbx),%rax
     0x0000000000401259 <+248>: mov    (%rax),%edx
     0x000000000040125b <+250>: cmp    %edx,(%rbx)
     0x000000000040125d <+252>: jge    0x401264 <phase_6+259>
     0x000000000040125f <+254>: callq  0x4016a9 <explode_bomb>
     0x0000000000401264 <+259>: mov    0x8(%rbx),%rbx
     0x0000000000401268 <+263>: sub    $0x1,%ebp
     0x000000000040126b <+266>: jne    0x401255 <phase_6+244>
     0x000000000040126d <+268>: add    $0x50,%rsp
     0x0000000000401271 <+272>: pop    %rbx
     0x0000000000401272 <+273>: pop    %rbp
     0x0000000000401273 <+274>: pop    %r12
     0x0000000000401275 <+276>: pop    %r13
     0x0000000000401277 <+278>: pop    %r14
     0x0000000000401279 <+280>: retq
```

The assembly code above comes from the phase_6() function of the binary bomb lab that I'm currently working on. I already realized that the code creates a linked list of 6 integers and should have no duplicate values. In order to diffuse the bomb, I would need to enter orders of the nodes such that the results of 7-X, where X is each of the six node values, come in descending order. In addition, the first node is located at 0x604300 and each subsequent node is located at 0x604310, 0x604320 and so on.

After printing the node values with print *(int*) statement, I got the following:

```
    Node1(0x604300): 897
    Node2(0x604310): 329
    Node3(0x604320): 897
    Node4(0x604330): 722
    Node5(0x604340): 214
    Node6(0x604350): 596
```

Now I'm confused! I thought there isn't suppose to be any duplicate values, but Node1 and Node3 have the same value of 897! I tried to proceed assuming these values are correct, by entering to the program the order (5 2 6 4 3 1) and (5 2 6 4 1 3), but both would trigger the explode_bomb() function as suggested by GDB.

I'm now very confused and have no idea which part of the assembly code I've mis-understood. Any hints would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Finally somebody who is not hopeless :)  From a quick glance I think they should be ascending not descending.

Comment: Also, the `7-x` applies to the input numbers (the node indices) not the node values.

Comment: Thank you so much Jester! I totally mis-understood the 7 minus part and that's why I ranked in ascending order (which would make the 7 minus results descending). Finally got this one diffused after spending a whole night on it. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [binary bomb lab phase 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323188/binary-bomb-lab-phase-6)